# links to theorem-environments take me to first page

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, links

I'm currently creating a big document with multiple TeX-files 
and used dozens of links to parts I put into theorem-environments. 
However, some of the links do not work, they just take me to the first 
page of the document.

It seems like using an 'enumerate-environment' 
at the beginning of the content of the 
thm-environment will cause the link associated to that thm-environment 
to take me to the first page (maybe I was not able to use 
'\label' correctly in this case).
Here is the code, after deleting most of the content and clearing the header:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}


% font, language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


%maths
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}


%general formatting  
\usepackage{enumitem}     


%environments
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Bemerkung}



%hyperref
\usepackage[
        colorlinks=true,
        urlcolor=purple,
        linkcolor=purple!87!black,
        pdfborder={0 0 0}
    ]{hyperref}







\begin{document}

\section{This is where the link takes me to}





\subsection{instead of remark 1.2}





\newpage



\begin{rem}\label{broken_ref}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
    \item
    relevant content.

    \item
    relevant content 2.
\end{enumerate}
\end{rem}


\begin{rem}\label{working_ref} 
If I do not begin the content of the remark with an 'enumerate-environment', 
it works...
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
    \item
    relevant content
\end{enumerate}
\end{rem}


\pagebreak


 Link that does not work $\to$ \ref{broken_ref} \reflectbox{$\to$}.\\

 Link that does   work $\to$ \ref{working_ref} \reflectbox{$\to$}.



\end{document}
```

Can someone explain to me, why it does not work, when I begin the remark with an enumerate environment ?

Comment: That is not very minimal. Are all of those packages really needed to reproduce the problem? Please delete those which can be deleted while still reproducing the problem. (And although I doubt you need `graphicx` at all for the MWE, I'm certain you don't need it twice.)

Comment: I reducid it :) 
It is for sure not minimal, but far more than before. 
I used \pagebreak to illustrate, that the link will 
take you to the first page, not to the second one, where the remark itself will be displayed.

Comment: This comment is about writing style, not the problem you pose. A label like `\label{ex3_5_1}` may confuse you (the author) when you move remarks around or add or delete some. You may find it easier to revise your document if you choose labels like `\label{rem:broken-link}` with semantic significance (for you).

Comment: Thanks Ethan :)
It took quite a while, but I finally followed your suggestion to support the reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a minimised example. I think that you need to define new theorems etc. after loading `hyperref` so that counters are set up correctly to give destination anchors unique names and so that targets of links work correctly. See section 3.2 of the package manual.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%hyperref
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=purple,
linkcolor=purple!87!black,
pdfborder={0 0 0}
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Satz}
\numberwithin{thm}{section}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Bemerkung}


\begin{document}

  \subsection{Auflösbarkeit algebraischer Gleichungen}

  \subsubsection{Auflösbare Gruppen}

    Define something...

  \pagebreak

  %THIS IS THE REMARK I WANT TO CREATE A LINK TO
  \begin{rem}\label{rem:ex3_5_1}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
      \item
      $[G,G]$ besteht aus allen endlichen Produkten
      von Kommutatoren aus $G$.
      \item
      $[G,G] \triangleleft G$ ist der kleinste Normalteiler $N \subset G$, sodass $G/N$ abelsch ist.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{rem}

  \pagebreak

  \ref{rem:ex3_5_1}

\end{document}
```